# Compiling generated protobuf files into a static library

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, static-libraries, static-linking

I have several projects that all depend on generated protobuf C++ files. The previous maintainer simply added the source to each target (causing the generated cpp files to be built multiple times). I thought I would save a little bit of time by building each protobuf cpp file once as a static library and linking them into each target as necessary.

Everything builds, but the target programs no longer function. I traced the error down to this code:

```
const google::protobuf::Descriptor *desc = google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::generated_pool()->FindMessageTypeByName("my.type");
google::protobuf::Message *msg = google::protobuf::MessageFactory::generated_factory()->GetPrototype(desc)->New();
```

The FindMessageTypeByName() method call always returns nullptr when I link in the protobuf files as a static library. Doing a little reading, I found out that [DescriptorPool::generated_pool()](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#DescriptorPool.generated_pool.details) contains protocol messages built at compile time:

> Generated protocol message classes which are compiled into the binary
> will allocate their descriptors in this pool.

This raises several questions (answering any of them would be very educational):

1. How does the protobuf library manage this registration? It feels like I would need to generate a function to run as a hook before main, or maybe a static list of initializer functions to call.
2. Is there a way to statically link precompiled protobuf cpp files in a way that they are automatically added to the generated pool?
3. If 2 is not possible, how would I add these precompiled proto files to a new pool?

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution to this problem?